# SQLite cursor returns 0

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to save the chat history in SQLite database. When I write to database, the app returns non-zero value so it is almost write to database correctly, But when I try to read the database data, the cursor returns 0 and no data retrieved form database. 
here is the code for creating database:

```
public class ChatDatabaseHelp extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    static String DATABASE_NAME;
    static int VERSION_NUM=1;
    public static String KEY_ID="key_id",KEY_MESSAGE="message";
    public static String TABLE_NAME="messages";
    public ChatDatabaseHelp(Context ctx)
    {
        super(ctx,DATABASE_NAME,null,VERSION_NUM);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String SQL="CREATE TABLE messages(key_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,message TEXT NOT NULL)";
        db.execSQL(SQL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

here is the code where I write and read from database:

```
public class ChatWindow extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText t_send;
    Button send;
    ChatAdapter messageAdapter;
    ListView listView;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    ArrayList<String> list;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_window);
        t_send=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        list= new ArrayList<String>();
        send=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        messageAdapter=new ChatAdapter(this);
        listView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
         final ChatDatabaseHelp helper=new ChatDatabaseHelp(this);

        db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
        System.out.println("hiiii"+helper.TABLE_NAME);
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("select * from messages "  , null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            list.add(cursor.getString(1));
            messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
                cv.put(helper.KEY_MESSAGE,t_send.getText().toString());
                db.insert(helper.TABLE_NAME,null,cv);


                list.add(t_send.getText().toString());
                t_send.setText("");
                messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
        });

    }
    private class ChatAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        public ChatAdapter(Context ctx){
            super(ctx,0);
        }
        public int getCount()
        {
           return list.size();
        }
        public String getItem(int position)
        {
            return list.get(position);
        }
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater=ChatWindow.this.getLayoutInflater();
            View result=null;
            if(position%2==0){
                result=inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_row_ingoing,null);
                TextView message=(TextView)result.findViewById(R.id.message_text_in);
                message.setText(getItem(position));}
            else{
                result=inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_row_outgoing,null);
                TextView message=(TextView)result.findViewById(R.id.message_text_out);
                message.setText(getItem(position));}


            return result;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        db.close();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have first write data into db then after read data if table is empty cursor give 0 value. above your code first read data into table that time is not found any data there for cursor give 0 value.
you used two button read and write into db.

first write data into db that code in below.

```
  write.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
            cv.put(helper.KEY_MESSAGE,t_send.getText().toString());
            db.insert(helper.TABLE_NAME,null,cv);


            list.add(t_send.getText().toString());
            t_send.setText("");
            messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    });
```

then after read the data into db below code..

```
  read.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            db=helper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("select * from messages "  , null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
                    list.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("message"));
                    messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    cursor.moveToNext();
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: the cursor still returns 0 also and data retrieved

Comment: It works correctly when i add button but when i close the activity and reopen it, the data is deleted and no values returned unless i write something new. @Android-Team